# Purging console.log file in Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, websphere-liberty

In production server we are facing a issues like console.log file inside logs folder is not purging automatically. It is growing more than a GB. so server space utilization is reaching 100%.

1. How to set maximum file size for console.log?
2. How to archive the console.log file?
3. Do we have any necessity to write the `logging` tag in server.xml before or after some particular tag? because in my old project i placed 'logging' tag at last and it works fine.

Server.xml file lines related to logging

```
<logging maxFileSize="10" maxFiles="6" messageFileName="messages.log" logDirectory="/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/servers/LibertyServer/logs" />
<logging consoleLogLevel="AUDIT"/>
```

initOptions.js

```
var wlInitOptions = {
    connectOnStartup : true,
    timeout : 60000,
    logger : {
        enabled: true, 
        level: 'debug', 
        stringify: true, 
        pretty: false,
        tag: {
            level: false, 
            pkg: true
        }, 
        whitelist: [], 
        blacklist: [],
        nativeOptions: {
            capture: true               
        }
    },
    analytics : {
        enabled: false
    }
```

};

Currently i can see all the logs in console.log file. I knew it is because of log level is set as AUDIT. To make a note we were using logger.send from device often to send the logs to server.

Worklight version 6.0.0.2
Liberty profile version 8.5.5.0-20130510-0831

if you need any info please comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note, `maxFiles` and `maxFileSize` does not apply to console.log.  Please carefully read:

[Liberty profile: Logging and Trace](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/rwlp_logging.html)

If you want Liberty log feature to manage log file size and file rollover, you should consider whether you really intend to use console.log or not.  I recommend to not use it, in your case.